# How to extend an Error in JavaScript with the correct flowtypes

Tags: javascript, error-handling, flowtype

I'm trying to create a custom error that extends `Error` with correct flowtypes

Example of what I'm trying to do:

```
export class ValidationError extends Error {
  /**
   * @constructor
   * @param {string} message - Error message
   * @param {object} inputData - Data that was validated
   * @param {object} invalidProperties - Specific properties of `inputData` that are invalid
   * @param {object[]} reasons - Reason the `inputData` is invalid
   */
  constructor(message, inputData, invalidProperties, reasons) {
    super()
    this.id = ''
    this.name = 'ValidationError'
    this.message = message
    this.inputData = inputData
    this.invalidProperties = invalidProperties
    this.reasons = reasons
  }
}
```

With types:

```
  /**
   * @constructor
   * @param {string} message - Error message
   * @param {object} inputData - Data that was validated
   * @param {object} invalidProperties - Specific properties of `inputData` that are invalid
   * @param {object[]} reasons - Reason the `inputData` is invalid
   */
  constructor(
    message: string,
    inputData: {...},
    invalidProperties: {...},
    reasons: Array<{...}>
  ) {
    super()
    this.id = ''
    this.name = 'ValidationError'
    this.message = message
    this.inputData = inputData
    this.invalidProperties = invalidProperties
    this.reasons = reasons
  }
}
```

(in tryFlow :
https://flow.org/try/#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)

But flow complains about the additional properties (`id`, `inputData`, etc). I tried working with interfaces, but flow doesn't like classes that `implement` and also `extend`.

Has anyone done this successfully?

Thanks in advance,
Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare that those propertied exist before you assign to them, e.g.

```
export class ValidationError extends Error {
  id: string;
  inputData: { ... };
  invalidProperties: { ... };
  reasons: Array<{ ... }>;

  // ...
```